# Change model to cache average rating with redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

In my rails app I have a product model where I have the following method:

```
def average_rating
        comments.average(:rating).to_f
end
```

this calculates the average rating that users give to products.

How can I make Redis cache the average rating?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In model

```
def average_rating
   Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/#{__method__}", expires_in: 1.hour) do
       comments.average(:rating).to_f
   end
end
```

In application.rb

```
config.cache_store = :readthis_store, { expires_in: 1.hour.to_i, namespace: 'foobar', redis: { host: config.redis_host, port: 6379, db: 0 }, driver: :hiredis }
```

In Gemfile

```
gem 'redis'
gem 'readthis'
gem 'hiredis'
gem 'redis-browser'
```

readthis - this is to not to crash when redis down.

hiredis - to make little faster

redis-browser - To see what is really cached.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So in #{cache_key}/#{__method__} i should put my own cache key and method?

Comment: Key only fine I think. __method__ will take the current method name automatically. Pls double check by printing that.

Comment: What value should I use as cache_key? For example product id or this value is auto generated?

Comment: Look like I found answer here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching